# How to return the nested object path from the object function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import json
import inspect
class obj:
    def __init__(self, dict1):
        self.__dict__.update(dict1)
    def return_path(self):
        //Something
        
def dict2obj(dict1):
    return json.loads(json.dumps(dict1), object_hook=obj)
family=dict2obj(json.load(open("test.json")))
```

I load a JSON file and create nested objects recursively, then I want to implement a function to return the path of the object instance called

e.g., family.grandparent.children.grandchildren.return_path() then it returns family.grandparent.children.grandchildren as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let each `obj` tell its children their paths, and store them.

```py
import json


class obj:
    def __init__(self, dict1):
        self.__dict__.update(dict1)

    def set_path(self, path):
        self.path = path
        for name, child in self.__dict__.items():
            if isinstance(child, obj):
                child.set_path(f"{path}.{name}")


def dict2obj(dict1):
    return json.loads(json.dumps(dict1), object_hook=obj)


family = dict2obj(json.load(open("test.json")))
family.set_path("family")
print(family.grandparent.children.grandchildren.path)
# 'family.grandparent.children.grandchildren'
```

If `path` might be a key, you can rename the attribute (e.g. to `path_`).

Comment: How am I going to get the path? Because I do not know the path, as the JSON to object is dynamic. Is there a way to do it in __init__ recursively?

Comment: Sorry, I missed a line. You can do `family.set_path("family")`, and it works out the path for every node. I've added it to the answer.